# ERROR: '[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: in testing

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, vue.js, karma-mocha, mocha-phantomjs

I am writing unit tests in a Vue 2.0 app using PhantomJS, Karma, Mocha and Chai and while the tests pass, I get a warning with each test that looks like this:

> ERROR: '[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: highlightjs
>   (found in <UnitTest>)

I would either like to find a way to ignore warnings about custom directives or somehow make the tests aware of them.

=== Possibly related, possibly separate error ===

When I force one of my tests to fail I am getting an error that looks like:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 16.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "unit"
npm ERR! node v7.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! vuestack@1.0.0 unit: `cross-env BABEL_ENV=test karma start test/unit/karma.conf.js --single-run`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the vuestack@1.0.0 unit script 'cross-env BABEL_ENV=test karma start test/unit/karma.conf.js --single-run'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the vuestack package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     cross-env BABEL_ENV=test karma start test/unit/karma.conf.js --single-run
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs vuestack
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls vuestack
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Other tests still pass but this error shows up when they've all run. Have tried uninstalling / reinstalling node modules, as well as switching Node versions around.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doh! Solved: 
`import VueHighlightJS from 'vue-highlightjs'
Vue.use(VueHighlightJS);`

I found the answer to the question [here](https://www.metachris.com/2017/05/how-to-test-vue.js-plugins-and-extensions/). Incidentally, a blog post by the creator of the component I was struggling with. Looks like you need to include custom components using Vue.use() in each separate testing file.